# Problemas na exibição da imagem com GD Lib

Tags: php

no front-end tenho o seguinte código

```
    $separador = explode('ID = ', $data['produto_nome']);
    $produtoSelecionado = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM gs_produtos WHERE id = '$separador[1]'" );

    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ).'/voucher.php">';
```

No Arquivo voucher.php tenho o seguinte código

```
// Header informando que é uma imagem JPEG
header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );

if( $produtoSelecionado ){

    foreach( $produtoSelecionado as $voucher );

        $path = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ).$voucher->voucher;

        // PEGA URL DA IMAGEM NO BANCO DE DADOS
        $voucherCliente = imagecreatefromjpeg( $path );

        // CORES DA SAIDA DA IMAGEM
        $cor = imagecolorallocate( $voucherCliente, 255, 255, 255 );

        // TEXTO 01 - ESCRITO NA IMAGEM
        $nome = urldecode( ucfirst( $data['userName'] ) );

        // ESCREVENDO NA IMAGEM
        imagestring( $voucherCliente, 5, 15, 515, $nome, $cor );

        // ENVIA IMAGEM PARA O BROWSER OU ARQUIVO
        imagejpeg( $voucherCliente, NULL, 80 );

}
```

tentei de várias formas, mas a imagem não aparece, simplesmente aparece aquele icone de imagem corrompida, é a primeira vez que utilizo essa lib e não estou conseguindo apresentar a imagem.

Comment: Tente comentar o `header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );` e vê se há alguma mensagem de erro. No error_log do PHP aparece algum erro relacionado?

Comment: @Thomas não exibe nenhum erro, mas no console do navegador diz que a imagem foi transferida como text/html

Comment: Tente colocar `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` antes do `header()` e comente o header. Creio que assim mostrará os possíveis erros.

Comment: @Thomas permanece sem erros

Comment: ele chega a entrar no if?

Comment: @Thomas entra no if tranquilo, se eu tentar fazer um include() ele tenta imprimir algo que começa assim, que são muitos caracteres que possívelmente deve ser a imagem ����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 80 ��C  %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(��C   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((��%a"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�

Comment: adicionando ob_start(); anted do imagejpeg() e isso depois dele $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();
   
   echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $rawImageBytes ) . "' />"; consegui exibir a imagem, porém sem o texto que eu quero escrever nela

Answer (score -1):

RESOLVIDO DESSA MANEIRA.

```
<?php
        // Header informando que é uma imagem JPEG
        header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );

        if( $produtoSelecionado ){

            foreach( $produtoSelecionado as $voucher );

                $path = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ).$voucher->voucher;

                // PEGA URL DA IMAGEM NO BANCO DE DADOS
                $voucherCliente = imagecreatefromjpeg( $path );

                // CORES DA SAIDA DA IMAGEM
                $cor = imagecolorallocate( $voucherCliente, 0, 0, 0 );

                // TEXTO 01 - ESCRITO NA IMAGEM
                $nome = urldecode( ucfirst( $data['userName'] ) );
                $cpf  = urldecode( $data['userCpf'] );

                echo $cpf;

                // ESCREVENDO NA IMAGEM
                imagestring( $voucherCliente, 5, 325, 108, $nome, $cor );

                ob_start();

                // ENVIA IMAGEM PARA O BROWSER OU ARQUIVO
                imagejpeg( $voucherCliente, NULL, 80 );

                $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();

                echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $rawImageBytes ) . "' />";

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: @Thomas resolvido velho!

Comment: Legal. Faltava um `ob_start()`, bem lembrado. Nos meus testes eu consegui fazer funcionar sem o `ob_start()`, vou procurar o porquê. Só uma dica pra facilitar: dê um echo na variável `$rawImageBytes`, já que no front-end você chama esse script no `src` da `<img>` e espera que retorne um `image/jpeg`. Fica estranho retornar uma `<img>`. Aliás, funciona?

Comment: E também, não se esqueça de aceitar essa como a resposta válida.

Comment: @Thomas eu ajustei isso não estou mais usando a <img> deixo o script retornar a imagem mesmo.